# use of the count function in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a small doubt, can I show the counted total of the rows instead of what it appears  below ,separately. Without using subqueries?

```
SELECT  COUNT(TEMA),tema
FROM LIBRERIAS 
WHERE TRIM(TEMA )LIKE 'GEO%IA'  AND EJEMPLARES BETWEEN 5 AND 20
GROUP BY tema;
```

[image]

I would like to get the total counted showed only one time. It is possible? Can i achieve this?
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the total counted"? What output do you want here? If it's *just* the total number of matching values, why use `group by` at all?

Comment: I would like it to show the total, which in this case would be 3, instead of 1, 1, and 1, the group by is ncesary is i want to show "tema" and use count. @JonSkeet

Comment: Look at some docs on [ROLLUP](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-rollup/).

Comment: So just `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM LIBRERIAS WHERE TRIM(TEMA) LIKE 'GEO%IA'  AND EJEMPLARES BETWEEN 5 AND 20` perhaps? (If not, why not? It would really help if you'd clarify what you're trying to achieve.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I just edited the question with thw result that i like to achieve without using subquery,, to achieve it i used ```SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(TEMA) FROM LIBRERIAS WHERE TRIM(TEMA) LIKE 'GEO%IA' AND EJEMPLARES BETWEEN 5 AND 20) AS TotalContado,
    TEMA
FROM
    LIBRERIAS
WHERE
    TRIM(TEMA) LIKE 'GEO%IA' AND EJEMPLARES BETWEEN 5 AND 20
GROUP BY
    TEMA; ```

Comment: `COUNT(TEMA)` and `COUNT(*)` are going to be the same thing unless `TEMA` contains nulls.

Comment: And as the query specifies `TRIM(TEMA) LIKE 'GEO%IA'` then TEMA cannot be null, so you should use the standard SQL expression, which is `count(*)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUM OVER` to get the total:

```
SELECT SUM(COUNT(tema)) OVER () AS total, tema
FROM librerias 
WHERE TRIM(tema) LIKE 'GEO%IA'
AND ejemplares BETWEEN 5 AND 20
GROUP BY tema
ORDER BY tema;
```

A more typical query result would be the result you already got along with a total row (using `ROLLUP`). Yet another, one single result row showing the count and the temas:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(tema) AS total,
  LISTAGG(tema, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tema) as temas
FROM librerias 
WHERE TRIM(tema) LIKE 'GEO%IA'
AND ejemplares BETWEEN 5 AND 20;
```